# using ng-if in ui-grid celltemplate not working

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use different links in my column based on recordType value . Here is my columndef for UI-Grid :

```
{                 
      name: app.localize('First Name'),
      field: 'firstName',
      enableHiding: false,
      cellTemplate: '<a ng-if=\"row.entity.recordType == Contact\"  href="#/tenant/data/editcontactrecord?id={{row.entity.id}}" class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{row.entity.firstName}}</a>'

            },
```

Above is one of the record Types. This is not working first Name is blank. Cannot figure out if there is a syntax issue. Also how to add multiple ng-ifs for cellTemplate ?

Answer (score 0):

try like that:

```
{
field: 'firstName',
displayName: app.localize('First Name'),
enableHiding: false,
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{row.entity.firstName}}</div>'
}
```

and about the if question.
the view:

```
<div ui-grid="gridObjectOptions"></div>
```

the controller:

```
    gridObjectOptions = {
    /////////////data to cycle (this is your ng-if)
    data: 'camerasEncoders.deviceList',
    onRegisterApi:function(gridApi){
    /////////////here you will be exposed to all the grid data it might be usefull
    },
    /////////////the column Defs we've just wrote, each element in the data will get the cell template you define here 
    columnDefs: [{
    field: 'firstName',
    displayName: app.localize('First Name'),
    enableHiding: false,
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{row.entity.firstName}}</div>'
    ]}
}
```

Hope it will be usefull, enjoy :)